# Python get date from days given

Tags: python, datetime

I need to calculate the date based on the number of minutes from the start of the year. I just need the day and month.

I have tried a few different classes within Python datetime but I can not get the desired result.

for example, at 1700 today, minutes since the 01/01/2022 is 263100

```
print(datetime.timedelta(0,0,0,0,263100))
```

This returns

> 182 days, 17:00:00

Before I explicitly write out the months and how many days they have and work it out that way, is there something already built in that I am missing within datetime?

Comment: The input is number of minute and you want to get the date ?

Comment: Did you tried timedelta?

Comment: `datetime(2022, 1, 1) + timedelta(minutes=263100)`…?

Comment: You already have a timedelta. Just add it to a datetime for the start of the year. That’s what timedeltas are _for_.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. We add the minutes `timedelta` to the start `datetime`, and return it formatted.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def datesince_min(min:int, start:tuple=(2022,1,1)) -> str:
    date = datetime(*start) + timedelta(minutes=min)
    return date.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S")
            
print(datesince_min(263100)) #Saturday, July 02, 2022 06:00:00
```

For more information regarding `strftime` formatting, refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

---

> Before I explicitly write out the months and how many days they have and work it out that way...

You shouldn't **ever** have to do that, and if you did it would almost certainly have to be for a system or language that is in development.

Answer (score -1):

I found this code that should do the trick:

```
number_of_days = ((datetime.timedelta(0,0,0,0,263100)).split())[0]
months = (number_of_days - years * 365) // 30
days = (number_of_days - years * 365 - months*30)
print(months, days)
```

Where you replace 263100 with whatever minutes you wish ofc

(source: [https://www.codesansar.com/python-programming-examples/convert-number-days-years-months-days.htm#:~:text=Python%20Source%20Code%3A%20Days%20to%20Years%2C%20Months%20%26,print%28%22Months%20%3D%20%22%2C%20months%29%20print%28%22Days%20%3D%20%22%2C%20days%29](https://www.codesansar.com/python-programming-examples/convert-number-days-years-months-days.htm#:%7E:text=Python%20Source%20Code%3A%20Days%20to%20Years%2C%20Months%20%26,print%28%22Months%20%3D%20%22%2C%20months%29%20print%28%22Days%20%3D%20%22%2C%20days%29))

:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).